# MongoDB $sum on object inside object.

Tags: mongodb

I got a table of invoices, each invoice got several invoiceLines.

I need a sum of all invoiceLines of all invoice records counted together.

```
db.invoice.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': { dueDate: { '$gte': 1413571600, '$lte': 1596163600 } } }, 
    { '$unwind': '$invoiceLines' }, 
    { '$group': { _id: '$_id', invoiceTotal: { '$sum': '$invoiceLines.amountTotal' } } }, 
    { '$project': { 
        "_id": 0, 
        "invoiceTotal": 1
    }
}])
```

Gives me the result:

```
{ "invoiceTotal" : 2000 }
{ "invoiceTotal" : 18000 }
{ "invoiceTotal" : 23000 }
{ "invoiceTotal" : 5000 }
```

Which is great, so far so good - now how do I count these together?

I want the result to just be:

```
{ "invoiceTotal" : 48000 }
```

I tried this without luck:

```
{ '$project': { 
    _id: 0, 
    "bookingTotal": {
        "$sum": {
            "$map": {
            "input": "$invoice",
            "as": "iv",
            "in": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$map": {
                    "input": "$$iv.invoiceLines",
                    "as": "il",
                    "in": "$$il.amountTotal"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried something like this:

```
{ "$addFields": {
     "invoiceTotal": 
           {
           $reduce: {
              input: {
               $reduce: {
                  input: "$invoice.invoiceLines",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: { $concatArrays : ["$$value", "$$this.amountTotal"] }
               }
             },
              initialValue: 0,
              in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this"] } 
           }
        }
   }}
```

But what ever I try, I get 4 results with null or blank.

Should I get rid of the group or the unwind or?

Comment: You should try `{ '$group': { _id: null, invoiceTotal: { '$sum': '$invoiceLines.amountTotal' } } }` instead of group by id when your expected output is to sum all the amounts for all invoice lines.

Comment: @Veeram how come you can always solve tings so simple?  Not fair! :-)  Once again thank you so much Veeram.  Write a short solution so I can mark your answer.

Comment: just to make sure I understand - grouping on `_id: null` tells mongo to do it on everything?